# Calculator history numberAppend function

Tags: javascript, html

I have this markup:

```
<div class="calculator grid">
    <div class="output">
        <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
        <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-all-clear>AC</button>
    <button data-delete>DEL</button>
    <button id="inactive" data-operation>()</button>
    <button data-devide data-operation>%</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operation>^</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operation>÷</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operation>*</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-equals id="equals">=</button>
    <button data-operation>+</button>
    <button data-operation id="minus">-</button>
</div>
```

and this code:

```
// Create calculator class
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement, historyLogElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
    this.historyLogElement = historyLogElement;
    this.clear();
    // calculator elements
  }
  // clear button function
  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = "";
    this.previousOperand = "";
    this.operation = undefined;
    this.historyLog = ""; // Initialize history log
  }

  delete() {
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0,-1);
    this.historyLog = this.historyLog.toString().slice(1);

  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    if (number === "." && this.currentOperand.includes(".")) return;
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
    
    // Prepend the entered number and a newline character to the history log
    this.historyLog = number + this.historyLog;
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {
    if (this.currentOperand === "") return;
    if (this.previousOperand !== "") {
      this.compute();
    }
    this.operation = operation;
    this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand;
    this.currentOperand = "";
    
    // Prepend the chosen operation and a newline character to the history log
    this.historyLog = operation + '\n' + this.historyLog;
  }
  
  compute() {
    let computation;
    const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand);
    const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand);
    if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return;
    switch (this.operation) {
      case "+":
        computation = prev + current;
        break;
      case "-":
        computation = prev - current;
        break;
      case "*":
        computation = prev * current;
        break;
      case "÷":
        computation = prev / current;
        break;
      case "/":
        computation = prev / current;
        break;
      default:
        return;
      case "^":
        computation = Math.pow(prev, current);
        break;
      case "%":
        computation = (prev * 100) / current + "%";
        break;
    }
    this.currentOperand = computation;
    this.operation = undefined;
    this.previousOperand = "";
  }

  getDisplayNumber(number) {
    const stringNumber = number.toString();
    const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split(".")[0]);
    const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split(".")[1];
    let integerDisplay;
    if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
      integerDisplay = "";
    } else {
      integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString("en", { maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
    }
    if (decimalDigits != null) {
      return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`;
    } else {
      return integerDisplay;
    }
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand);
    if (this.operation != null) {
      this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = `${this.getDisplayNumber(this.previousOperand)} ${this.operation}`;
    } else {
      this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = "";
    }
  this.historyLogElement.innerText = this.historyLog;
  }
}

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]");
const equalsButton = document.querySelector("[data-equals]");
const deleteButton = document.querySelector("[data-delete]");
const allClearButton = document.querySelector("[data-all-clear]");
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector("[data-previous-operand]");
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector("[data-current-operand]");
const historyLogElement = document.querySelector("[data-log]");
const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement, historyLogElement);

numberButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});

operationButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});

equalsButton.addEventListener("click", (button) => {
  calculator.compute();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});

allClearButton.addEventListener("click", (button) => {
  calculator.clear();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", (button) => {
  calculator.delete();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  let patternForNumbers = /[0-9]/g;
  let patternForOperators = /[+\-*/]/g;
  if (event.key.match(patternForNumbers)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.appendNumber(event.key);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
  if (event.key === ".") {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.appendNumber(event.key);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
  if (event.key.match(patternForOperators)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.chooseOperation(event.key);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
  if (event.key === "Enter" || event.key === "=") {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.compute();
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
  if (event.key === "Backspace") {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.delete();
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
  if (event.key == "Delete") {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.clear();
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
});
```

Why numbers in history are displayed in revers? I don't understand... I switched properties all day, I'm going crazy

I switched `this.currentOperand` with number and hoped will get all the numbers above in order to display operation order in history, instead got all numbers on one row and operator signs on another row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the existing log with the operation: `this.historyLog = this.historyLog + '\n' +  operation` and `this.historyLog = this.historyLog + number`

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement, historyLogElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
    this.historyLogElement = historyLogElement;
    this.clear();
    // calculator elements
  }
  // clear button function
  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = "";
    this.previousOperand = "";
    this.operation = undefined;
    this.historyLog = ""; // Initialize history log
  }

  delete() {
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0,-1);
    this.historyLog = this.historyLog.toString().slice(1);

  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    if (number === "." && this.currentOperand.includes(".")) return;
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
    
    // Prepend the entered number and a newline character to the history log
    this.historyLog = this.historyLog + number;
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {
    if (this.currentOperand === "") return;
    if (this.previousOperand !== "") {
      this.compute();
    }
    this.operation = operation;
    this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand;
    this.currentOperand = "";
    
    // Prepend the chosen operation and a newline character to the history log
    this.historyLog = this.historyLog + '\n' +  operation;
  }
  
  compute() {
    let computation;
    const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand);
    const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand);
    if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return;
    switch (this.operation) {
      case "+":
        computation = prev + current;
        break;
      case "-":
        computation = prev - current;
        break;
      case "*":
        computation = prev * current;
        break;
      case "÷":
        computation = prev / current;
        break;
      case "/":
        computation = prev / current;
        break;
      default:
        return;
      case "^":
        computation = Math.pow(prev, current);
        break;
      case "%":
        computation = (prev * 100) / current + "%";
        break;
    }
    this.currentOperand = computation;
    this.operation = undefined;
    this.previousOperand = "";
  }

  getDisplayNumber(number) {
    const stringNumber = number.toString();
    const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split(".")[0]);
    const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split(".")[1];
    let integerDisplay;
    if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
      integerDisplay = "";
    } else {
      integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString("en", { maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
    }
    if (decimalDigits != null) {
      return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`;
    } else {
      return integerDisplay;
    }
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand);
    if (this.operation != null) {
      this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = `${this.getDisplayNumber(this.previousOperand)} ${this.operation}`;
    } else {
      this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = "";
    }
  this.historyLogElement.innerText = this.historyLog;
  }
}


const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]");
const equalsButton = document.querySelector("[data-equals]");
const deleteButton = document.querySelector("[data-delete]");
const allClearButton = document.querySelector("[data-all-clear]");
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector("[data-previous-operand]");
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector("[data-current-operand]");
const historyLogElement = document.querySelector("[data-log]");
const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement, historyLogElement);

numberButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});

operationButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});

equalsButton.addEventListener("click", (button) => {
  calculator.compute();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});

allClearButton.addEventListener("click", (button) => {
  calculator.clear();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", (button) => {
  calculator.delete();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  let patternForNumbers = /[0-9]/g;
  let patternForOperators = /[+\-*/]/g;
  if (event.key.match(patternForNumbers)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.appendNumber(event.key);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
  if (event.key === ".") {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.appendNumber(event.key);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
  if (event.key.match(patternForOperators)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.chooseOperation(event.key);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
  if (event.key === "Enter" || event.key === "=") {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.compute();
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
  if (event.key === "Backspace") {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.delete();
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
  if (event.key == "Delete") {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.clear();
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  }
});
```

```html
   <div class="calculator grid">
        <div class="output">
        <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
        <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
        </div>
        <button data-all-clear>AC</button>
        <button data-delete>DEL</button>
        <button id="inactive" data-operation>()</button>
        <button data-devide data-operation>%</button>
        <button data-number>1</button>
        <button data-number>2</button>
        <button data-number>3</button>
        <button data-operation>^</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-number>5</button>
        <button data-number>6</button>
        <button data-operation>÷</button>
        <button data-number>7</button>
        <button data-number>8</button>
        <button data-number>9</button>
        <button data-operation>*</button>
        <button data-number>.</button>
        <button data-number>0</button>
        <button data-equals id="equals">=</button>
        <button data-operation>+</button>
        <button data-operation id="minus">-</button>
    </div>
    <div data-log></div>
```

Comment: Tried that,  will display numbers in history on one row and this.operation on new rows in history.
thanks

Comment: @Displayname if this solved your problem don't forget to accept my answer (the checkbox), thanks

Comment: Yes it worked actually, i haven't paid attention on the exact line of code and swapped the wrong way first times.